# Transform time issue (gmapping & stage)

Tags: navigation, simulation, stage, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.11.0) on a x64 AMD Dell Inspiron. I use ROS release Noetic with the following relevant package versions:

```
ros-noetic-simulators/focal,now 1.5.0-1focal.20211007.220413 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-slam-gmapping/focal,now 1.4.2-1focal.20211007.214554 amd64 [installed]
ros-noetic-stage/focal,now 4.3.0-1focal.20210423.222334 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-stage-ros/focal,now 1.8.0-1focal.20210922.193922 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf/focal,now 1.13.2-1focal.20210922.193350 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf-conversions/focal,now 1.13.2-1focal.20210922.204930 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210423.225547 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2-eigen/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210423.225948 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2-geometry-msgs/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210922.190831 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2-kdl/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210922.190836 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2-msgs/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210423.225302 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2-py/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210922.180952 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-noetic-tf2-ros/focal,now 0.7.5-1focal.20210922.190247 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/8mPxzSED) is my launch script. I am ultimately trying to use `move_base`, `stage_ros` and `gmapping` together. For now, nevermind my navigation stack configuration, I followed this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup). I am having problems with misaligned clocks between the stage simulator and gmapping. See the transform tree below:

[link](https://imgur.com/a/X6FcI7u)

Notice how the oldest transform for `map -> odom` by gmapping is very large (I suspect a Unix timestamp) versus every other transform published by stage which are relative to the elapsed time. This difference is causing the navigation stack to give me the following error(s):

> [ WARN] [1637419863.630355767]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Lookup would require extrapolation 1637419854.238633871s into the past.  Requested time 4.700000000 but the earliest data is at time 1637419858.938633680, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]. canTransform returned after 0.10044 timeout was 0.1.

How do I fix the transforms published by gmapping in this case?

**EDIT:**

I have found a hack solution for a working-ish system by adding the following to the launch file:

```
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
<param name="~transform_publish_period" value="0.1" />
```

The first line launches a `/clock` server as a time reference that all nodes must use. This seems necessary since stage is using relative simulator time and gmapping is using real wall time. See this [article](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock). The second line changes how frequently gmapping publishes the `map -> odom` transformation. The default 0.05 caused every node to constantly print:

> Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame odom at time 2.550000 according to authority unknown_publisher at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp

> [ WARN] [1637431235.428923806, 2.500000000]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame odom at time 2.550000 according to authority unknown_publisher

Increasing to 0.1s causes only one warning in the beginning. I now have an issue with my program that I'm writing not being able to see the transform, i.e. `tf.canTransform('/base_link', '/map', rospy.Time())` returns `False`, until a few seconds after it starts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391336/transform-time-issue-(gmapping-&-stage)/) by [mxl367](https://answers.ros.org/users/90024/mxl367/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have solved it at last. The final launch file, ignoring the navigation stack for now, looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find mypkg)/launch/default.rviz"/>
    <node name="stage" pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros" args="--clock $(find mypkg)/data/map.world"/>

    <node name="slam" pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" args="scan:=base_scan">
        <param name="transform_publish_period" value="1"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

Notice I increased the `transform_publish_period` to a whole second, which curiously doesn't raise any errors. Also, below is the code I mentioned earlier, which now successfully publishes the estimated pose. Some bits are unnecessary and rough (e.g. do I really need the `tf_callback`?) but it's a start:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import *
from nav_msgs.msg import MapMetaData, OccupancyGrid
import tf
from tf.msg import tfMessage

class Explorer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tf = tf.TransformListener()
        self.tf_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/tf', tfMessage, self.tf_callback)
        self.map_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/map', OccupancyGrid, self.map_callback)
        self.pose_pub = rospy.Publisher('/estimatedpose', PoseStamped, queue_size=1)

    def tf_callback(self, msg):
        pass

    def map_callback(self, msg):
        head = msg.header
        info = msg.info
        data = msg.data

        if self.tf.canTransform('/base_link', '/map', rospy.Time()):
            p,q = self.tf.lookupTransform('/base_link','/map',rospy.Time())
            pose = Pose(Point(*p), Quaternion(*q))
            estp = PoseStamped()
            estp.pose = pose
            estp.header.frame_id = 'map'
            print(estp)
            self.pose_pub.publish(estp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('explore')
    node = Explorer()
    rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [mxl367](https://answers.ros.org/users/90024/mxl367/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-23**:
Great. You can accept your own answer by clicking on the check mark